# Php:undefined variable derived from array

Tags: php

I have an array say $packages. I have the code like this to prevent the undefined variable error.

```
$hospital_charge=0;
    if(!empty($packages)){
    foreach($packages as $package){
        $hospital_charge=$package['hospital_charge'];
```

Then in subsequent code I use

```
$health_card_discount = ((($a*5)/100)+($hospital_charge*.05));
```

That is if $hospital_charge have a null value, I get the error 
`undefined variable hospital_charge`,

so to prevent that I defined $hospital_charge=0

is this the proper way of doing it or there is better way of achieving this?

Note:I am using PHP 5.4.16

Comment: Yes It's valid , you can also use `isset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `isset` (it will check that the variable is defined and not null:

```
$health_card_discount = isset($hospital_charge) ? ((($a*5)/100)+($hospital_charge*.05)) : (($a*5)/100);
```

But the way you are doing it is also valid.

Comment: Thanks taxicala - Assuming that you want to check both `$a` and `$hospital_charge` with `isset` how you can achieve that?

Comment: Same way, use a ternary comparison but i recomend moving the code to a function with an if statement.